# Reset shared library state between googletest cases

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm trying to write isolated tests for a memory allocator that I've been working on using [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/). When I run more than a single gtest, the memory allocator carries over the state from other previous tests. This is because the memory allocator interface is global and the shared library appears to be loaded only once.

Is there a built in way tell [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) to reload shared libraries between test runs so I can have better test case isolation?

Comment: Do you know how to reload the shared library (in a program that does not involve Google Test at all)? If so, I suggest you add that detail to your question, so that people can focus on either the "call a function after every Google Test test case" vs "reload a shared library".